# Can you update the version of the command "watch"?

Tags: bash

Can you update the version of the command "watch"?

I read that the newer version supports the option --color, but I don't know where I can find a newer version. I'm using SLC/CentOS 6.

```
$ watch --version
0.2.0
```

Comment: You already have the current version it appears http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793126/colors-with-unix-command-watch

Comment: To update the watch package, use `sudo yum update procps-ng`. If you get `No packages marked for update` then you have the "latest" available for your distro.